# Brackets in Monarch language not working / not folding

Tags: monaco-editor

I am trying to write a Monarch language definition with custom brackets and I expected this to yield to the highlighting of the other bracket and to automatic code folding hints. I tried to make the sample as minimal as possible:

[official monarch test page](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html)

My language:

```js
return {
  defaultToken: 'invalid',
  brackets: [["1","2", "delimiter.angle"]],
  tokenizer: {
    root: [
      [/1|2/, "@brackets"],
      [/a/, { token: 'keyword.ae', bracket: '@open' }],
      [/e/, { token: 'keyword.ae', bracket: '@close' }],
      [/_/,""],
    ]
  },
};
```

Sample text:

```
_
1
_
2
_
a
_
_
_
_
e
_
_
_
_
```

I tried both ways of brackets. I expect `1` and `2` to form a fold/bracket as well as `a` and `e`. The syntax highlighting works, but no folding or other bracket highlighting:

[image: result with marked missing code folding]